# Inserting Text into a Designmode Iframe Triggered By a Button Outside the Iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, designmode

I have an editable iframe and I would like to insert text at the cursor location when the user  clicks a button that is outside the iframe.  I am trying to use the following code to insert the text:

```
function insertAtCursor(iframename, text, replaceContents) {
      if(replaceContents==null){replaceContents=false;}
      if(!replaceContents){//collapse selection:
         var sel=document.getElementById(iframename).contentWindow.getSelection()
         sel.collapseToStart()
      }
      document.getElementById(iframename).contentWindow.document.execCommand('insertHTML', false,     text);
};
```

I think that this is failing because the focus changes when I go to click the button.  However, I am not sure how to correct this.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct about the focus shift affecting your code insert.

Using the jQuery library, you can shift focus back to the iframe in the button's click binding:

```
$('#button').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#iframe').focus();
    insertAtCursor('iframe', 'test-text', null);
});
```

In pure javascript, shift focus before executing insertAtCursor() like so:

```
document.getElementById('iframe').focus()
```

Comment: I got the code you suggested to work without using the event.preventDefault() line.  However, every other time the button is pushed the iframe looses focus.  The text is inserted in the proper location but if the user tries to type it will not go into the iframe.  To combat this I tried adding this line: if(document.activeElement.id!='home_codeframe') { $('#home_codeframe').focus(); }.  However, this did not work.  Any thoughts on how to fix this?  Thank you.